# Templated Variables Bug With Lambdas in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, lambda, visual-studio-2017, c++14, variable-templates

[c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) provides [variable templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) Which work fine in [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017), but within lambdas they seem to fall apart. For example:

```
template <typename T>
const auto PI = std::acos(static_cast<T>(-1));

int main() {
  auto func = []() { cout << PI<float> << endl; };

  func();
}
```

[On gcc 6.3](https://ideone.com/P2bg5s) this outputs:

> 3.14159

On Visual Studio 2017 this outputs:

> 0.0

Comment: Isn't this an obvious compiler bug? I mean, imagine if this was intended behavior *shudder*

Comment: Interesting.  Confirmed with MSVC 19.00.23918 (Visual Studio 2017 desktop).

Comment: It is the `auto` in template that is failing, if changed to `T` it works as expected

Comment: @KillzoneKid Wow, that would make an excellent workaround answer.

Comment: @JonathanMee I don't know why it fails though, so maybe someone can take over

Comment: @Justin thank you I did in fact mean to paste that part of the code into the question.

Comment: @JonathanMee Actually I seem to remember there was a question about `static_cast` failing under similar circumstance. So maybe nothing to do with `auto`, it just cannot deduce the correct type.

Comment: Looks like it may be an optimizer issue? Does `-Od` work for you?

Comment: @AndyG Yes indeed great comment. Putting it in the capture of the lambda also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wierd bug, but it seems to have a reliable workaround, which works for both, this case and the [related case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118587/division-in-variable-template-returns-zero-in-visual-studio-2017). In both cases forcefully activating template seems to do the job in VS2017:

```
template <typename T>
const auto PI = std::acos(static_cast<T>(-1));

int main() 
{
  PI<float>; // <------ this
  auto func = []() { std::cout << PI<float> << std::endl; };

  func();
}
```

GCC 6.3 for example: https://ideone.com/9UdwBT

Comment: And those people tried to pursue the Committee to incorporate their compiler's features into the Standard.

Comment: @bipll Low hopes, they cannot even fix the [code submission format](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/207741/template-needs-to-be-force-instantiated-vs2017-bug.html) on their bug tacker

Comment: Can you please post this in the linked question as well. It is the correct solution as it identifies the actual problem, namely that the `PI<float>` template doesn't seem to initialize automatically. There's an answer over there, which gets lucky and solves the problem but doesn't address the underlying issue and I'm loath to accept it.

Comment: @JonathanMee [Sure thing!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132236/8746007)